# serverless invoke local with mocked SNS event

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, serverless-framework

I'm having some trouble invoking locally using [`serverless`](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/invoke-local/).

Using Python3.6 runtime

The function in `serverless.yml` is:

```
functions:
  myFunction:
  events:
    - sns: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789:myTopic
```

My command is

```
sls invoke local -f myFunction -s dev -r us-east-1 -p events/myMockedSnsMessage.json
```

Serverless doesn't like the syntax on the `myMockedSnsMessage.json`

When I log the event in my lambda function I get something like:

```
{
  'Records': [
    {
      'Sns': {
        'Message': '{"version":"0","id":"a965ce94-fcb2-ad15-319d-04adab1072d0","detail-type":"AWS API Call via CloudTrail",...}'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

That is, the SNS message is a string with valid JSON inside

How should I store a mock event for an SNS message and still have valid JSON so serverless doesn't yell at me for bad JSON syntax?

Comment: What's the code in `myMockedSnsMessage.json`? I bet that it is invalid. Please include it in your question.

Comment: The json comes directly from the [sns event source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-sns) received by Lambda.  The `Message` attribute is a string of JSON

Comment: Include it in your question please. Does it look like the JSON in Trent's answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use double-quotes, and stringify the json. e.g.

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "Sns": {
        "Message": "{\"version\":\"0\",\"id\":\"a965ce94-fcb2-ad15-319d-04adab1072d0\",\"detail-type\":\"AWS API Call via CloudTrail\",...}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you need more examples, the AWS documentation has [sample events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-sns) that you can modify, and when you use AWS console to test your lambda, you can select many different event templates from a dropdown.